# Error instancia de un objeto utilizando JsonConvert

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos, tcp, referencias

Un saludo a todos los que se molesten en leer esto e intentar ayudarme.
Estoy haciendo una aplicación que utiliza el protocolo TCP.
Obtengo el error **System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto** cuando ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
public static bool AgregarCajero(Cajero cajero)
    {
        try
        {

            MensajeSocket<Cajero> mensaje = new MensajeSocket<Cajero> { Metodo = "AgregarCajero", Entidad = cajero };

            clienteStreamWriter.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mensaje));
            clienteStreamWriter.Flush();
            return true;
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió el error: " + ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Ese mismo código lo utilicé con éxito para almacenar otros objetos, pero con el objeto Cajero me sale error, ¿Alguien sabe qué puedo hacer?
Las propiedades de Cajero son las siguientes:

```
public class Cajero
{
    String usuario;
    String nombre;
    String primerApellido;
    String segundoApellido;
    int caja;
    bool activo;
    int codigoCajero;

    public string Usuario { get => usuario; set => usuario = value; }
    public string Nombre { get => nombre; set => nombre = value; }
    public string PrimerApellido { get => primerApellido; set => primerApellido = value; }
    public string SegundoApellido { get => segundoApellido; set => segundoApellido = value; }
    public int Caja { get => caja; set => caja = value; }
    public bool Activo { get => activo; set => activo = value; }
    public int CodigoCajero { get => codigoCajero; set => codigoCajero = value; }
}
```

Gracias, espero que alguien pueda ver el error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En que linea te da el error? igual para este error hay una respuesta generica que te va a servir por lo menos para hacer un debug de tu problema...

Comment: Si eso no soluciona tu problema, se mas especifica de donde esta el problema...